# Blocking request to port 80 on gateway on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, ip-blocking

I want to block access to the gateway (192.168.1.1) on port 80, to prevent network user from trying to access the router setup.  I'm using Ubuntu 9.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP -p tcp --to-destination 192.168.1.1:80 -i eth0
```

Change `--to-destination 192.168.1.1:80` to the IP address of the gateway.

Change `-i eth0` to the interface that you need the rule on.

Note that this will completely block all access to that IP/port combination unless you create a specific rule to allow traffic from one IP, like perhaps an administrative workstation.